# Create list view webpart using office UI fabrics in SPFX

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to implement same list view webpart as given in this [Office fabric component example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist/customitemcolumns) article. They have provided code for the same but I don't know how to implement this code.

I have created new spfx solution with choosing react js framework & copy pasted provided code in above article to .tsx file. But I dont know what to do next.  Can anyone please help me step by step to implement this webpart.

Thank You.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing recently. Could you suggest me the best approach to do this ?